# Java list of punctuation characters?

Tags: java

Is there a way to get a list of all characters that `Pattern` considers as punctuation?

In other words, can I get `{Punct}` characters from somewhere as a reference without copy/pasting them myself? I have looked at `Pattern` and `Character` but can't figure out where it is defined and if it even is public?

The characters in question are: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...can I get {Punct} characters from somewhere as a reference without copy/pasting them myself? I have looked at Pattern and Character but can't figure out where it is defined and if it even is public?

For the POSIX character class, it's defined in package-protected class `java.util.regex.ASCII` -- and not as a list of characters, but as an array that maps integral ASCII values to character classes.

It's good to strive for a single definition. However, depending on what you're trying to do, your best bet may be to copy and paste from the list of characters in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have only one idea to try this one:

```
public static boolean isPunctuation(char ch) {
    return !Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch) &&
           !Character.isWhitespace(ch) &&
            Character.isAlphabetic(ch);
}
```

Comment: This isn't the question, I am looking for a list of all characters that are considered punctuation, not a way to test if a character is punctuation :) I am testing them using regex `\\p{Punct}`. I need all those characters.

Comment: Then `[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@\\[\\\\\]^_`\\{|\\}~]` us the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may try

```
    public boolean check(char ch) {
        return "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~".indexOf(ch) != -1;
    }
```

Comment: This isn't the question, I am looking for a list of all characters that are considered punctuation, not a way to test if a character is punctuation :) I am testing them using regex `\\p{Punct}`. I need all those characters.